# My balance is 0.00 after update. What to do?

Tags: balances

I updated my Mist Wallet to 0.9.3 on Mac. When I started it, I saw that my balance is 0.00 which isn't true. Etherchain shows 24 ETH for my wallet. 
It has nothing to do with syncing. Everything is correct concerning this.
I tried to restore my wallet using the backup files. When I started it, I saw the correct amount just for a second, before it was counted down to zero in front of my eyes.

I have no idea what to do. Any ideas, any help?
Many thanks in advance!!!